# Use a python dictionary to insert into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, pymysql

I am trying to take the data from a dictionary (the example is simplified for readability) and insert it into a mysql database. 
I have the following piece of code.

```
import pymysql 
conn = pymysql.connect(server, user , password, "db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    ORFs={'E7': '562', 'E6': '83', 'E1': '865', 'E2': '2756 '}
    table="genome"
    cols = ORFs.keys()
    vals = ORFs.values()
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (
    table, ",".join(cols), ",".join(vals))

    print sql
    print ORFs.values()
    cur.execute(sql, ORFs.values())


    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

the `print sql` statement returns
`INSERT INTO genome (E7,E6,E1,E2) VALUES(562,83,865,2756 )`
when I type this directly into the mysql command line, the mysql command works. But when I run the python script I get an error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: not all arguments converted during string formatting
      args = ('not all arguments converted during string formatting',)
      message = 'not all arguments converted during string formatting'
```

As always, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (
    table, ",".join(cols), ",".join(vals))
```

This SQL includes values and `cur.execute(sql, ORFs.values())` has values, too.

So, it should be `cur.execute(sql)`.

Comment: it gets a problem when there is non str value

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer doesn't work for non string dictionary value. This one is a revised version.

```
    format_string = ','.join(['%s'] * len(dict))
    self.db.set("""INSERT IGNORE INTO listings ({0}) VALUES ({1})""".format(", ".join(dict.keys()),format_string), 
                         (dict.values()))
```

Comment: Python versions prior to 3.7 does not guarantee to preserve dictionary insertion order. Version 3.6 does this but only from version 3.7 this is a part of a spec.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I will skip null columns.

```
data = {'k': 'v'}
fs = ','.join(list(map(lambda x: '`' + x + '`', [*data.keys()])))
vs = ','.join(list(map(lambda x: '%(' + x + ')s', [*data.keys()])))
sql = "INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (table, fs, vs)
count = cursor.execute(sql, data)
```